# Problem with Pointer Arithmetic in Doubly-Linked List Implementation

Tags: c++, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement doubly-linked list for learning purposes. It my first try, so I have some troubles along the way. The code is:

```
class List 
{
public:

    class Iterator;

    using value_type = int;
    // using allocator_type = Allocator;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference = Node&;
    using const_reference = const Node&;
    // using pointer = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer;
    using pointer = Node*; // TODO remove after lifting
    // using const_pointer = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::const_pointer;
    using const_pointer = const Node*;
    using iterator = Iterator;
    using const_iterator = const Iterator;

    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        Iterator() = default;
        Iterator(const Iterator& it): curr{ it.curr } {}
        Iterator(Node* n): curr{ n } {}

        Node* current() { return curr; }
        void operator=(Node* it) { curr = it; }
        Node* operator++() { curr = curr->next; return curr; }
        Node* operator++(int)
        {
            auto temp{ curr }; curr = curr->next; return temp;
        }
        Node* operator--() { curr = curr->prev; return curr; }
        Node* operator--(int)
        {
            auto temp{ curr }; curr = curr->prev; return temp;
        }
        bool operator==(const Iterator& it) const
        {
            return this->curr == it.curr;
        }
        bool operator!=(const Iterator& it) const{ return !( *this == it ); }
        Node& operator*() { return *curr; }
        Node* operator->() { return curr; }
    private:
        Node* curr;
    };

    List() = default;
    List(const std::initializer_list<value_type>& lst);

    value_type front() { return first->val; } // access the first element
    value_type back() { return last->val; } // access the last element

    iterator begin() { return first; }
    const_iterator begin() const { return first; }
    iterator end() { return last; }
    const_iterator end() const { return last; }

    bool empty() const { return sz == 0; } // check whether the container is empty
    size_type size() { return sz; }

    void clear(); // clear the content
    iterator insert(iterator iter, const value_type& elem); // insert elem
    // after iter
    // void emplace(const value_type& elem); TODO find out about that member

    void erase(iterator it);
    void push_back(const value_type& elem);
    void pop_back();
    void push_front(const value_type& elem);
    void pop_front();
    
    ~List()
    {
        clear();
        delete first;
        delete last;
    }

private:
    pointer first{ new Node{0, nullptr, last} };
    pointer last{ new Node{0, first, nullptr} };
    size_type sz{ 0 };
};

void List::clear()
{
    if(empty()) return;

    while(first->next != last)
    {
        erase(first->next);
    }
    sz = 0;
}
```

I was advised to make it work on `int` for the start and then make it a template. The problem is that I can't do something like:

`auto temp{list.begin()};`
`while(temp != list.end()) {...; ++temp;}`

I just get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error. The reason, as I realise, in this:

```
int main()
{
        List lst;
    
        std::cout << &( lst.first ) << " adress of first\n";
        std::cout << &( lst.last ) << " adress of last\n";
        std::cout << &( lst.first->next ) << " adress of first->next\n";  
         
        return 0;
    }
```

The result:

```
0x7ffde43c6500 adress of first
0x7ffde43c6508 adress of last
0x5573f5d73eb8 adress of first->next
```

But in the default constructor of List `first->next` IS 'last'. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: As #Some programmer dude explain(stupid error of mine) code above prints a location of pointers to `first` and `last`, so changing the code like this:

```
int main()
{
        List lst;
    
        std::cout << &( *lst.first ) << " adress of first\n";
        std::cout << &( *lst.last ) << " adress of last\n";
        std::cout << &( *(lst.first->next) ) << " adress of first->next\n";  
         
        return 0;
    }
```

I get this output:

```
0x55b111d77eb0 adress of first
0x55b111d77ed0 adress of last
0 adress of first->next
```

And also he pointed out that the problem is the wrong order of initialisation - `first` initialised to point to `last` before the `last` even had been created.

Comment: Please note that `&( lst.first )` is the location of the `first` member in the `lst` object, not where it actually point (which would be plain `lst.first`, without the pointer-to operator `&`).

Comment: What is your `clear()` function doing? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Oh, and one problem is the initialization of `first`... You use `last` *before* it's initialized. No matter what order `first` and `last` are initialized (they will be initialized in that order by the way) one of them is going to use an uninitialized pointer. It's only logical if you just think about it for a while... The initialization of `first` depend on the initialization of `last` which depends on the initialization of `first`... and so on.

Comment: As a simple solution for the initialization order of `first` and `last`, define your own default constructor which does the initialization of both (just `new Node`, nothing more) then *assign* to the members of the nodes inside the `List` constructor body.

Comment: #Some programmer dude thanks a lot for your help, I think that's the problem

Comment: #Some programmer dude, I added the code for the `clear()`, but I don't even have an example because I didn't finish to implement the List yet. The purpose is to clear list and `delete` all the Nodes allocated on free space

Comment: I think a major problem is that you're trying to do too much at once. Slow down, don't try to write your whole program, or even your whole class, at once. Start with an empty `main` function and nothing else. Build, with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors. And when it builds cleanly then test. Once it works add a *small* and *simple* bit of code. Build and test. Ad the next small and simple bit. And so on. When there's a problem it's easier to isolate it into a [mre] and to debug it.

Comment: #Some programmer dude, thank you for your advice